# Displaying attachments on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, attachment, images

I need to display attachments on a visual force page for the Case object.

This is the code I am using. I had it working for awhile, but it somehow broke down. It gets all the attachments, but it will not show the images.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Case.attachments}" var="att">
            <apex:panelgrid columns="1">
                <h1>Image/h1>
                <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!att.Id}"/>
            </apex:panelgrid>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Case.attachments}" var="att">
    <apex:panelgrid columns="1">
        <h1>Image</h1>
        <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.id)}"/>
    </apex:panelgrid>
</apex:repeat>
```

Let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
        <apex:repeat value="{!Case.Attachments}" var="att">
            <apex:panelgrid>
                <apex:image styleClass="vitality-check-img" url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att)}" rendered="true"/>
            </apex:panelgrid>
        </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to display the files so the users can download them. Instead of using apex:image, do this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!att.Id}" target="_blank">View File</apex:outputLink>
```

This ensures to display all kinds of file, be it pdf or jpeg or text.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No, the attachments need to be viewed on the page, not download links. Otherwise it would be practical to just add the attachment related list to the page @heisenberg

Comment: I think you should remove this "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" and pass the att Id only. Have you tried this? - <apex:image value="/{!att.Id}"/>